# setOnLoadCallback: Trying to load a Google Visualization on a button press as opposed to on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm loading a basic line chart onto my page using the Google Visualization API.

Currently, this chart appears immediately when the page loads.  Previous posts on Stack indicate that this is due to google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization) which essentially replaces the .ready event.

I don't want this chart to load immeidately, but instead after a user clicks a button.  I'm having trouble porting this "drawVisualization" function into a function that's independent of the load.

Thank you!!!
Dan

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['gauge']});
  **google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);**
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Label', 'Value'],
      ['Memory', 80],

    ]);

    var options = {
      width: 400, height: 120,
      redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
      yellowFrom:75, yellowTo: 90,
      minorTicks: 5
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

function foo(){
I'd love to trigger the chart from here!!!!
}

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['gauge']});

  function foo() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Label', 'Value'],
        ['Memory', 80],
      ]);

    var options = {
      width: 400, height: 120,
      redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
      yellowFrom:75, yellowTo: 90,
      minorTicks: 5
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="foo()">Test</input>
```